# form values, I don't want to reset them

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am preparing a webpage that contains several forms, each one has the usual input text and submit button which calls a php script. The thing I don't like much is that whenever I press one of the submit button the others input text are reset. I am wondering if there is a way to keep the value of the input texts the one I have entered even if I'll press a submit button..
thanks!

Comment: so have the backend fill out the forms once again. You have the data on the server, use it.

Comment: If he have several forms he won't have the data on the server, only the data of the form he submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is that you can store data into $_SESSION ... like :

$_SESSION['forms_data']['firts_form_name'] = array(
'field1' => $_REQUEST['field1'],
'field2' => $_REQUEST['field2']
....
);
and for others the same principle.

then you can retrieve them again from the $_SESSION arr,

Answer (score 1):

Make your forms use Ajax, even the submitted form won't reset, this way you have full control on what to reset and what to keep.

Comment: But if the page is reloaded/refreshed ??

Comment: if you refresh the page while you're typing your answer or comment on stackOverflow, do you find your editing?.....

Answer (score 1):

two ways:
  - *server side :* use `$_SESSION`
  - *client side :* use `sysphus.js`

**Reference :**[`Auto-Save User’s Input In Your Forms With HTML5 and Sisyphus.js`](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/05/sisyphus-js-client-side-drafts-and-more/)

Answer (score 1):

what about using JQuery and submiting via ajax ?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this..

```
<input type='text' value='<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['user-name']) ) ? $_REQUEST['user-name'] :'' )?>' name='user-name'/>
```

On submit of your form..you can get your values back in filed.

Comment: Mmm that seems simple.. I've just tried out but I think there is an error since my page doesn't work anymore

Comment: There is a error in my code try this   <input type='text' value='<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST['user-name']) ) ? $_REQUEST['user-name'] :''  ?>' name='user-name'/>

Answer (score 0):

`function clear_form_elements() {
       document.getElementById('your form id').reset();
}`